# Html pages and one css page

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a website for my college project and I want to make it as good as possible. I basically want to have several HTML pages for my website which I have setup but I want to use only the one CSS page. So basically if I edit one page, for example my second page, how do I change the look of it without editing any of the CSS for my first page. I have tried several things but I honestly have no idea.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a template for your HTML pages and then link an external style sheet in your `<head>` section of each page like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css">
```

Then for any special cases that are not part of the template, you can link additional style sheets. Just a side note, embedding styles in elements directly is harder to maintain than linking multiple CSS files.

If you are allowed to use JavaScript, you might like to use a JavaScript template engine like [Handlebar.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

The beauty of template engines is that you can define sections and create dynamic HTML. This may be more complex than what you're wanting here, but it is very cool.

A large list of template engines can be found here: http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

Comment: ok so i have added that on to each html page thank you, so what should i display it like on the css page to edit what each page looks like .

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. If you define CSS classes, you can add classes to your elements to style them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just change the layout of each page in CSS, CSS is not aware of what the page you are at.

Either do you change the layout by changing the whole CSS file. Or you try to put the CSS special functions for that page inside the page elements.

Otherwise you can't do that!

For example:

You can create a single CSS file and link it as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" type="text/css">
```

Then in each page, where you want the style to be different you can change the style inline:

```
<element style="property: value; property_2: value_2;"></element>
```

Like this!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a class to the body tag on the second page, then specifying the style that are just for that page by using the class.

Page one:

```
<body>
  <p>This page is boring</p>
</body>
```

Page two:

```
<body class="page-two">
  <p>That's a mighty fine body</p>
</body>
```

Then your CSS could be

```
p {
  background: white;
}
.page-two p {
  background: red;
}
```

If you have a lot of extra CSS to apply to the second page, then you might consider using LESS or something similar to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your best method is to have an app.css file that has global settings like height, width... and then have specific page files index.css, portfolio.css.. that have specific styles like colors.
You can specify your button general style in your app.css, and then more specific styles in each page css file.

app.css:

```
       button{
           height: 30px;
           width: 150px;
           border: 1px solid purple;
           color: purple;
      }
```

index.css:

```
      button{
          border: 1px solid black;
          color: black;
      }
```

Add the app.css to each html file, and then only the specific page css file to each html file.  This will make it easy to expand in the future.